# What's meant by "the illusion of the chapel ended" in The Just Men of Cordova?

Tags: meaning, the-just-men-of-cordova, edgar-wallace

In [chapter 17 of The Just Men of Cordova](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks08/0800311h.html#chap17) (1917) by Edgar Wallace, the author is describing a captured man who had been led to a building:

> The sight he saw was a remarkable one. **He was in a chapel**; he saw the stained-glass windows, but in place of the altar there was a low platform which ran along one end of the building. It was draped with black and set with three desks. It reminded him of nothing so much as a judge's desk, save that the hangings were of purple, the desks of black oak, and the carpet that covered the dais of the same sombre hue.
>
> Three men sat at the desks. They were masked, and a diamond pin in the cravat of one glittered in the light of the huge electrolier which hung from the vaulted roof. Gonsalez had a weakness for jewels.
>
> The remaining member of the Four was to the right of the prisoners.
>
> With the stained-glass windows, the raftered roof, and the solemn character of the architecture, **the illusion of the chapel ended.** There was no other furniture on the floor; it was tiled and bare of chair or pew.
>
> Black took all this in quickly. He noted a door behind the three, through which they came and apparently made their exit. He could see no means of escape save by the way he had come.
>
> The central figure of the three at the desk spoke in a voice which was harsh and stern and uncompromising. "Morris Black," he said solemnly, "what of Fanks?"
>
> Black shrugged his shoulders and looked round as though weary of a question which he found it impossible to answer.
>
> "What of Jakobs, of Coleman, of a dozen men who have stood in your way and have died?" asked the voice.
>
> Still Black was silent. His eye took in the situation. Behind him were two doors, and he observed that the key was in the lock. **He could see that he was in an old Norman chapel** which private enterprise had restored for a purpose.

**It's already said at first the he was in a chapel, so does the author meant here that Black firstly guessed that he was in a chapel, then he became totally sure of that?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The writer is playing with definitions a little, the room has the form of a chapel and has been a chapel in Norman times, but has now been restored to meet a non-ecclesiastical purpose and no longer has the *function* of a chapel.

This is why it has the built features of a chapel, but not the furnishings of one.

This causes a dissonance where the form is initially recognised, then the impression is over-ridden by closer observation then the fact of its adapted and original functions mesh to an understanding of the rooms changes over time.

Answer (score 1):

The stained-glass windows, raftered roof, and solemn character of the architecture gave the *illusion* of being a chapel. But that was all.  Nothing else about the room looked like a chapel.  The illusion ended after those three things.